# Button with two expressions to evaluate depending on state

Tags: dynamic, button

I miss a `Button`-like interface element which would behave like `Checkbox` but ***evaluate*** expressions instead of changing value of a `Dynamic` variable. Specifically:

1. The button should remember its state like `Checkbox`: when the (not pressed) button is clicked it should evaluate specified expression *and keep pressed apppearance*.
2. When *pressed* button is clicked it should evaluate *another* expression and become *visually not pressed*.
3. It would be very useful to have the state of the button dependent also on values of a some other shared variables (in order to have ability to change the state of the button via another interface elements like `Checkbox`es). But changing its state in this way shouldn't lead to evaluation of the corresponding expressions. It should influence only further behavior of the button.

How to approach this in an efficient way if number of such buttons (independent from each other and having different sets of expressions to evaluate) may be about 15?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76486/discussion-on-question-by-alexey-popkov-button-with-two-expressions-to-evaluate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP really needs to provide a *clear* problem specification, since I still completely fail to understand what is meant by recent comment:

> The problem with #3 is how to make state be dependent also from a set of other shared variables.

But here is an extendable version of the code I provided in my recent comment.

```
Clear[state, expr, toggler];
state[1] = False;
state[2] = False;
expr[1, False] := Print["The first checkbox was off"];
expr[2, False] := Print["The second checkbox was off"];
expr[1, True] := Print["The first checkbox was on"];
expr[2, True] := Print["The second checkbox was on"];
toggler[i : (1 | 2)] := 
  Button["Change state N" <> ToString[i], state[i] = ! state[i]];
Grid[
 Table[With[{i = i}, {Checkbox[
     Dynamic[state[i], (expr[i, state[i]]; state[i] = #) &]], 
    toggler[i]}], {i, 2}]]
```

Now each checkbox evaluates an expression that is dependent on the index of the checkbox and its current state: `expr[i, state[i]]` (so no need for an `If` statement any more). Each chekbox is also supplied with a button that toggles the state, but doesn't evaluate expressions.

Here's another example that replicates the behavior of the example provided by OP:

```
Clear[state, expr, groupExpr, group];
group = False;
state[1] = False;
state[2] = False;
groupExpr[ownState_] := (state[#] = ownState) & /@ Range[2];
expr[1, stateVec_] := (group = Or @@ stateVec);
expr[2, stateVec_] := (group = Or @@ stateVec);
Column[
 Prepend[
  Table[With[{i = i},
   Checkbox[Dynamic[state[i], (state[i] = #; expr[i, state /@ Range[2]]) &]]],
   {i, 2}],
  Checkbox[Dynamic[group, (group = #; groupExpr[group]) &]]
  ]
 ]
```

Most generally, I would write the following:

```
Clear[state, expr, groupExpr, group, n];
n = (* some n *);
group = False;
(state[#] = False) & /@ Range[n];
groupExpr[ownState_, 
   stateVec_] :=(* some code dependent on own state and other states *);
expr[i_, ownState_, 
   stateVec_] :=(* some code dependent on own state, index, and other \
states *);
Column[
 Prepend[
  Table[With[{i = i}, 
    Checkbox[
     Dynamic[state[
       i], (state[i] = #; 
        expr[i, state[i], state /@ Range[n]]) &]]], {i, n}],
  Checkbox[
   Dynamic[group, (group = #; groupExpr[group, state /@ Range[n]]) &]]
  ]
 ]
```

Definitions for `expr[i,...]` might need to be supplied explicitly for all possible values of `i`, depending on the complexity of the logic.

Finally, here's a generalization to two overlapping groups:

```
Clear[state, expr, groupExpr, groups, reverseGroups];

n = 6;
groups = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 6}};
reverseGroups = First /@ Position[groups, #] & /@ Range[n];

(group[#] = False) & /@ Range[Length@groups];
(state[#] = False) & /@ Range[n];

groupExpr[i_, ownState_] := (state[#] = ownState) & /@ groups[[i]];
expr[i_, stateVec_] := (group[#] = Or @@ stateVec[[groups[[#]]]]) & /@ reverseGroups[[i]];

Column[Join[
  Table[With[{i = i}, 
    Checkbox[Dynamic[group[i], (group[i] = #; groupExpr[i, group[i]]) &]]],
    {i, Length@groups}],
  Table[With[{i = i}, 
    Checkbox[Dynamic[state[i], (state[i] = #; expr[i, state /@ Range[n]]) &]]],
    {i, n}]
  ]]
```

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: @Alexey would you like me to replicate your example in some sufficiently general way?

Comment: Yes, it would be useful.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov does this work?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I would be glad also for generalization for arbitrary number of groups (only elements from the group influence the group's `Checkbox`).

Comment: Here is some example data: `{{eklig,1,4.77085},{eklig,2,9.7631},{eklig,3,7.14118},{eklig,4,9.56533},{eklig,5,1.3176},{klyhl,1,4.7085},{klyhl,2,8.37818},{scnij,1,1.20007},{scnij,2,8.75027},{scnij,3,3.94897},{scnij,4,7.74367},{mtlzo,1,7.22901},{mtlzo,2,4.9934},{mtlzo,3,4.84138}}`. First elements are names of groups, second are numbers inside the groups and third are data points.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Added an example for two overlapping groups. I can't say I like your notation too much, so I've used my own, but it should be quite simple.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, there is a deficiency here, of course: turning on group 2 turns on checkboxes `3` and `4`, which, in principle, should turn on group `1`, but this requires still extra code. At some point there are simply too many edge cases to handle.

Answer (score 0):

In comments [LLlAMnYP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26956/lllamnyp) suggested to use second argument of `Dynamic` for evaluation of an expression. Here is a complete solution based on this idea:

```
n = 3; group[1] = True;
Checkbox[Dynamic[group[1], 
  group[1] = #; 
   If[group[1], Do[element[i] = True, {i, n}], 
    Do[element[i] = False, {i, n}]]; &]]
Table[With[{i = i}, element[i] = True; 
  Checkbox[Dynamic[element[i], 
    element[i] = #; 
     If[Or @@ (element /@ Range[n]), group[1] = True, 
      group[1] = False]; &]]], {i, n}]
```

This is a simple two-level selection interface: elements are splitted into groups (here is only one group) and we can include or exclude a group by checking or unchecking the group `Checkbox`es. We also can do this element-by-element and it will influence the state of the group checkbox (here group is counted as included if at least one element from the group is included).